# removing pie chart outline text

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have placed a pie chart download from high charts but I have some issues I wanted to remove the text coming outlined of the pie chart can any one help me out and let me know how is this possible

```
var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
    categories = ['MSIE', 'Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Opera'],
    data = [{
        //y: 56.33,
        color: colors[0],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'MSIE versions',
            categories: ['General Public (Local)'],
            data: [<?php echo $company_details[0]['individual']; ?>],
            color: colors[0]
        }
    }, {
        //y: 10.38,
        color: colors[1],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'Firefox versions',
            categories: ['Foreign (Ind. & Inst.)'],
            data: [<?php echo $company_details[0]['foreign']; ?>],
            color: colors[1]
        }
    }, {
        //y: 24.03,
        color: colors[2],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'Chrome versions',
            categories: ['Institutional'],
            data: [<?php echo $company_details[0]['institutions']; ?>],
            color: colors[2]
        }
    }, {
        //y: 4.77,
        color: colors[3],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'Safari versions',
            categories: ['Directors / Spouses'],
            data: [<?php echo $sum_all_details; ?>],
            color: colors[3]
        }
    }, {
       // y: 0.2,
        color: colors[5],
        drilldown: {
            name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
            categories: [],
            data: [],
            color: colors[5]
        }
    }],
    browserData = [],
    versionsData = [],
    i,
    j,
    dataLen = data.length,
    drillDataLen,
    brightness;

// Build the data arrays
for (i = 0; i < dataLen; i += 1) {
// add browser data
browserData.push({
    name: categories[i],
    y: data[i].y,
    color: data[i].color
});

// add version data
drillDataLen = data[i].drilldown.data.length;
for (j = 0; j < drillDataLen; j += 1) {
    brightness = 0.2 - (j / drillDataLen) / 5;
    versionsData.push({
        name: data[i].drilldown.categories[j],
        y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
        color: Highcharts.Color(data[i].color).brighten(brightness).get()
    });
}
}

// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total percent market share'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            shadow: false,
            center: ['50%', '50%']
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '%'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Browsers',
        data: browserData,
        size: '30%',
        dataLabels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.y > 5 ? this.point.name : null;
            },
            color: '#ffffff',
            distance: -30
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Versions',
        data: versionsData,
        size: '90%',
        innerSize: '40%',
        dataLabels: {
            formatter: function () {
                // display only if larger than 1
                return this.y > 1 ? '<b>' + this.point.name + ':</b> ' +
                    this.y + '%' : null;
            }
        },
        id: 'versions'
    }],
    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 250
            },
            chartOptions: {
                series: [{
                    id: 'versions',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
    });
```

I am unable to figure out how do I remove the text that is showing in the outlined area the text is visible out area of the chart can anyone help me out 
[image]

Comment: Is my answer helping you? If yes then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have placed dataLabels property under plotOptions but it should be under pie object.
Your code

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        shadow: false,
        center: ['50%', '50%']
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    }
}
```

Place dataLabels under pie of plotOptions, Sample code below:

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        shadow: false,
        center: ['50%', '50%']
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/obu73hfw/) link for reference.